# How to send form validation error message through URI?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a page to change user password in Codeigniter. It's located in URI `admin/admin_page/change_password`. How can I send the error message? Because if I use redirect the message won't be shown.

My views are inside the switch statement. Here are my views:

```
case "change_password":
echo '<div class="panel-body">
<center><h2 style="font-family:baloo bhaijaan">Ganti Password</h2>
<form method="post" action="'.base_url('admin/change_password_action').'">
<div class="form-group">
<strong >Password lama</strong>
<h6 style="font-size: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px">'.form_error('password').'</h6>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" class="form-control" value="" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<strong>Password baru</strong>
<h6 style="font-size: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px">'.form_error('password_baru').'</h6>
<input type="password" name="password_baru" id="password2"  placeholder="**********" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<strong>Konfirmasi Password baru</strong>
<h6 style="font-size: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px">'.form_error('password_baru2').'</h6>
<input type="password" name="password_baru2" id="password3" placeholder="**********" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<p>
<button type="submit" style="font-family:baloo bhaijaan" name="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-succes">Ganti password</button>
</form>
</div>';
break;
```

Here is my controller:

```
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {   
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
       if (!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))) {
           $data['error_data'] = $this->session->flashdata('error');
       }    
       redirect('admin/admin_page/ganti_password');
   }
   else
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store your errors in flash data and display where you redirect.

Send Error Message like :

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
```

Print Error (for View)

```
if (!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))) {

    echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
}
```

Error (for controller)

```
if (!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))) {

    $data['error_data'] = $this->session->flashdata('error');
}
```

Comment: where do i put the if(!empty...??) @dev odedra

Comment: Whenever you want controller or view.

Comment: i've edited my controller as ur suggestion but the error message still dissapear, am i use the code right? see my edited question above @dev odedra

Comment: just do this in controller 
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {  
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
}

and in view 
if (!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))) {

    echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
}

Answer (score 1):

```
//using flash data you display error message, no need to pass any thing through URI

/* controller side */
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',  'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_baru', 'Password Baru',  'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_baru2', 'Password Baru2',  'trim|required');
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

           $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
           redirect('admin/admin_page/change_password');

      } else { 
               /*your action*/
      }

/* Views */
In admin/admin_page/change_password views page any where put below code to display error message. it will appear when page redirect time only. if you refresh flash message will vanish automaticlly

echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
 echo validation_errors('<b>','</b>'); //this will display individual input errors
```

Comment: it works, but if i try to type wrong input to every form, it shows direcly 3 message. as you can see in my view, i have 3 form and i want each form got 1 message. sorry for my bad english, @Ayyappa amara

Comment: i have modified as per your question... please implement from your end and confirm

Comment: echo validation_errors(<b>,</b>) <-- this part always show error 'unexpected '<' ... @Ayyappa amara

Comment: i am sorry, please use like this; echo validation_errors('<b>','</b>');

Comment: not yet bro,  the error not shown anymore but the error message also dissapear  @Ayyappa amara if you need the whole code i can provide pastebin